# Dropdown Menu Not Showing On Certain Page

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a website for a client and can't figure out what's going on - probably been looking at code too long.

You can see that the navigation menu is working on this page as far as drop down menus are concerned:

http://www.envisionforce.com/

However, on this page the drop downs aren't showing:

http://portal.envisionforce.com/

Any idea what needs to be changed to fix this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An initial look seems to indicate the second link isn't including the required JavaScript file. Did you forget to add the JavaScript for the menus to each page?

It looks like you are loading `wp-content/themes/Minos/data/combined4963.js?ver=1.1` on your main page, but not on the other pages. That file contains the needed menu dropdown JavaScript.

**Edit: I have confirmed this as the issue, the site works when adding that script to the page via the dev console.**

Comment: Hmmm I hadn't noticed that but just tried adding and it's still the same :(

Comment: Too high in the page, it has to be loaded after jQuery. Put it right above `</head>`. Next time, try looking at the console if you use FireBug/Google Chrome :)

Comment: After that, you have a rendering error in your CSS. Create a new style like this: `#top_bg { position:relative;z-index: 10000000; }` to fix. Without this, the submenus appear under the topbar element.

Comment: @RogueCoder Did you have to go through all those .js files to find the dropdown code, or did you already know it was there?

Comment: @ElefantPhace Chrome dev tools are a wonderful thing :)

Comment: nice! I'll check that out! +1 for awesomeness!

Comment: That got it working but broke one other thing.  I created a new question for that so everything is easier to track for anyone who needs help with this stuff in the future:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193788/page-not-loading-after-adding-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The file handling the dropdown menus (`whmcs.js`) is binding the behavior to the click event of elements `.dropdown-toggle` and `a.menu`

```
jQuery("html").bind("click", function (e) {
jQuery('.dropdown-toggle, a.menu').parent("li").removeClass("open");
});
```

Your markup on the page does not include these elements.

```
<li id="menu-item-1966" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1966">
<a href="http://portal.envisionforce.com/cart.php">
<b>SERVICES</b>
</a>
```

You need to add the appropriate classes to the `li` and `a` elements

**EDIT: OP got it right. Ignore this mumbo jumbo.**