# Page Not Loading After Adding Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the page in question:

http://portal.envisionforce.com/cart.php?gid=20

This javascript code has been added to the page header:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.envisionforce.com/wp-content/themes/Minos/data/combined4963.js?ver=1.1'></script>
```

When that isn't there, the page loads correctly but the drop down menus for the navigation don't work.  What needs to be changed to make both work?

Comment: I get an error on page load in the JavaScript console. Open your developer tools and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the jQuery UI plugin which that script depends upon. Add this script ABOVE the line you added.

```
<script type='text/rocketscript' data-rocketsrc='wp-content/themes/Minos/js/jquery-ui4963.js?ver=1.1'></script>
```

If you aren't using Firefox with FireBug or Google Chrome, install Google Chrome now. Then you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to access the developer tools, which has a JavaScript console that shows you errors that occur on your page. Invaluable for debugging.

Comment: I'm installing Chrome right now actually - I just added that above and it still isn't loading the slider form on the page... :(

Comment: Basically that script you load has a crap ton of dependencies. Now it's erroring out because Cufon is missing. The best option would be to extract JUST the submenu code from the script instead of using the entire script (which is massive).

Comment: `ctrl + shift + j` is a nice shortcut to dive right into the console.

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't know that one. +1

Comment: Tried editing quite a bit and nothing seems to be fixing it.  Right now I removed the line of javascript and the form is displaying correctly but there's no dropdown in the navigation.  Guess that will have to do for now.